# gauge: rotate the needle

Tags: javascript, raphael

i'm building a gauge widget with raphaeljs, starting with
http://renatoalbano.github.com/raphael-gauge/ example..

I don't understand what the criteria is for select a particular "center" for the needle:
in the first example the center of the needle is [140, 5] and the second is [67, 13]... how the author calculate it?

..and can i place the needle like this 
[image: gauge]
or it's necessary to place it in the middle of the circle/gauge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://renatoalbano.github.com/raphael-gauge/gauge-pointer.png

The little dot that the gauge pivots on is 67 px right and 13 px down from the top left of the image in this original orientation. That's how you need to slice and measure your image. ("Pivot point" would be a much better way for Raphael docs to explain it than "center point", it's confusing.)

You'll want to attach your background to the gauge at about 97, 81, assuming you crop that gauge image right to its edges (~193x193).

That's gonna look really cool when it's done ;^)